# How to change password complexity requirements in Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: password

I am trying to setup some OLD laptops with Ubuntu 14.04LTS at an elementary school.  I would like a simple password for the students to type but the password I am choosing keeps failing password complexity requirements.  I have tried to edit the `/etc/pam.d/common-password` file with the `minlength=1` and all of the other changes but this doesn't seem to make any difference.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

You only need to use

```
sudo passwd <user>
```

This will skip all requirements.

Warning: this will break automatic decryption if you encrypted your disk.

Answer (score 1):

By default, you should have a line like this in `/etc/pam.d/common-password`:

```
password [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so obscure sha512 try_first_pass
```

Remove `obscure` and add `minlen=1` (or whatever rules you want):

```
password [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so sha512 try_first_pass minlen=1
```

With this, you can set the password to be very simple, like `a`.

Comment: I tried your instructions and unfortunately it did not work. Here is what I am doing to test it- I go into System Settings - User Accounts - unlock egpl - Click on password and enter a - It says Not Good Enough and the Change button is still grayed out.

Comment: Ah- it might be that tool is using a different way to check password complexity. If you open a terminal as the user you want to change the password as and run the <code>passwd</code> command, does it allow you to change the password then?

Comment: No. I am new to Ubuntu so I will let you know what I did so in case that is part of the problem.  I logged in as the user egpl and then at a terminal screen I entered passwd.  It immediately comes up and says Permission denied password unchanged.  If I put in passwd egpl it says the same thing.  I appreciate your help with this.  I am eager to get these laptops into the hands of the students!

Comment: What does the password line look like in your /etc/pam.d/common-password file?

Comment: password [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so sha512 try_first_pass minlen=1

Comment: It is almost like the system isn't even using this file to determine password complexity at all.